# How to create bread crumbs from navigation list dynamically with ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I am having trouble figuring out how to create dynamic bread crumbs that are pulled from navigation.

I have an html nav page, and the crumbs are supposed to be pulled from this page. If the HTML changed, the bread crumbs is supposed to be changed as well.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no set way of doing breadcrumbs, its all custom based on what you're trying to let the user navigate back to.  Without providing anymore information in your description, there really isn't much assistance one can give with this.  Give more details on what you're trying to navigate between.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I really understand what you mean but, if you mean cookies?, you can set cookies in this way:

**Create a cookie:**

```
<%
    Response.Cookies("WEB_SITE_NAME")("Navigation")=myNavigation
    Response.Cookies("WEB_SITE_NAME").Expires = Now()+5
%>
```

**Read from previously created cookie:**

```
<%
    myNavigation = Request.Cookies("WEB_SITE_NAME")("Navigation")
%>
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I am not looking for cookie scripting. I have an html list on one page. What I am trying to do is to use this list to build the crumbtrail for the rest of the site.